# Templates for Visual Studio 2008 missing after full install of Standard Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, visual-studio-templates

I have a server with something called **Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU** which only provides templates for SSIS work. I did not remove that before installing the VS 2008 Standard Edition (at the end of this there was no demand for a reboot). I then installed the Service Pack 1 for this VStudio product (again, no order for a reboot).

To my surprise, Visual Studio 2008 still exposes the limited set of templates for SSIS stuff. I rebooted and the IDE still acts the same with just this little set of choices related to SSIS projects.

Yet, when I visit **Help -> About**, I get a more complete looking set of components. In fact, the ProjectTemplates subfolder appears to have everything I selected during install (C#, VB, and Web).

Is there some way to gain access to things like "web application project" templates or do I need to remove everything and start over?

-- EDIT update 6/24/2010 --
What a sad Setup package for a major product like Visual Studio 2008!

Here is what I discovered:

```
* VS2008 "shell" was the source of the whole problem described above
* I removed this "shell" (whatever that means) and that action alone did not fix the problem
* I removed the entire VS2008 Std Edition product
* I reinstalled the entire VS2008 Std Edition product
* Now all templates are present as they should be.
```

What a sorry installation package that could not somehow grapple with the situation that this "shell" thing was installed beforehand!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a sad Setup package for a major product like Visual Studio 2008!

Here is what I discovered:

```
* VS2008 "shell" was the source of the whole problem described above
* I removed this "shell" (whatever that means) and that action alone did not fix the problem
* I removed the entire VS2008 Std Edition product
* I reinstalled the entire VS2008 Std Edition product
* Now all templates are present as they should be.
```

What a sorry installation package that could not somehow grapple with the situation that this "shell" thing was installed beforehand!!!

Answer (score 0):

The leftovers are beause you have SQL Server 2008 developer tools installed and they use the same DevEnv IDE.

If you want your Web / Windows / etc development tools available, you are going to have to install them.

Comment: Everything is fully installed (like I wrote above). The templates are there but only the SSIS templates are exposed by the IDE. I am still guessing about what to do. Remove everything and start over?